# Partitioning positive divisors of 100!

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, problem-solving, factorial

Is it possible to partition all positive divisors of 100! (including 1 and 100!) into 2 subsets so that each subset has the same number of integers and the product of all the divisors making up the first subset is equal to all divisors making up the second subset?

I have been trying to answer this problem using trial and error and have still not gotten to an answer. I was wondering whether there is an alternative method to simply trial and error. Additionally, I am also still finding it a bit hard to comprehend what the question is asking. I would really appreciate it if you explained to me how to do this question in an easy-to-understand manner. Thank you.

Comment: That's how the question was asked?  I can't make heads or tails of the second part of the question ("the product of all the divisors...").

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to write the last phrase. I have added it now.

Comment: @Macavity: Why not? Take the non-square $24$ for example, with subsets $\{1,2,12,24\}$ and $\{3,4,6,8\}$.

Comment: @barakmanos My mistake.  But then the answer is evident too - will post below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$100!=$

$2^{50+25+12+6+3+1}\cdot3^{33+16+8+4+2+1}\cdot5^{20+10+5+2+1}\cdot7^{14+7+3+1}\cdot$

$11^{9+4+2+1}\cdot13^{7+3+1}\cdot17^{5+2+1}\cdot19^{5+2+1}\cdot23^{4+2+1}\cdot$

$29^{3+1}\cdot31^{3+1}\cdot37^{2+1}\cdot41^{2+1}\cdot43^{2+1}\cdot47^{2+1}\cdot$

$53^1\cdot59^1\cdot61^1\cdot67^1\cdot71^1\cdot73^1\cdot79^1\cdot83^1\cdot89^1\cdot97^1$

---

Since $100!$ has a prime factor that appears an odd number of times, it is not a perfect square.

Hence the number of divisors of $100!$ is even, and every divisor $d$ can be paired with divisor $\frac{100!}{d}$.

---

Moreover, the number of divisors of $100!$ can be easily calculated as:

$98\cdot65\cdot39\cdot26\cdot$

$17\cdot12\cdot9\cdot9\cdot8\cdot$

$5\cdot5\cdot4\cdot4\cdot4\cdot4\cdot$

$2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2=k$

So define subset #$1$ as $\{d_i|i\in[1,\frac{k}{4}]\cup[k-\frac{k}{4}+1,k]\}$ and subset #$2$ as $\{d_i|i\in[\frac{k}{4}+1,k-\frac{k}{4}]\}$.

Comment: @Macavity: Didn't follow what you posted up until now. Was busy fixing my original answer, in which I calculated the number of divisors using $98+65+\dots$ instead of $98\cdot65\cdot\dots$. But yes, it does look similar (with a lot more details I suppose).

Comment: @Macavity: No, I realized the number of divisors being divisible by $4$ as the "if and only if" condition for the answer to be yes when I gave you that comment with "$24$". It just took me a while to reformat my answer properly.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:  For every $x \mid 100!$, we have $100/x $ also as a divisor.  So keep all such pairs together for a product of $100!$.  If we can now establish that the number of divisors is a multiple of $4$, we are done.

P.S. for showing the latter, it is sufficient to note that there are at least two primes, say $97, 89$ which have an odd exponent in the prime factorisation of $100!$.